# Get Relational entity data with NSDictionaryResultType in coredata

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I am having an entity says "Questions" which have One-to-many relation with another entity "AnswerOptions". I am using `NSFetchRequest` to get data from entity table. I can get array of NSManagedObject, but I don't want to get it as NSManagedObject. I want to get it as an array of `NSDictionary`.

I have used `NSDictionaryResultType` for NSFetchRequest's ResultType. I am getting the data of "Question" entity but not getting it's associated "AnswerOptions".

Please let me know how to get data of a relational entity using `NSDictionaryResultType`.

Comment: The documentation doesn't state that it'll necessarily do anything for dictionary results, so this is a clutching-at-straws guess and not an answer, but have you tried `
relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching`?

Comment: @Tommy I tried this but not making any difference when I use `NSDictionaryResultType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question there is no indication that you actually *need* the `NSDictionaryResultType`. I strongly recommend that you use the usual managed object result type instead. This will make your life so much easier.

There are very few cases where you need the dictionary, e.g. in really tight memory situations with loads of data and serious performance challenges. Otherwise, just fetch the objects - they are key-value-coding compliant so they are just as easy to use as dictionaries.

In fact, the documentation of `propertiesToFetch` states clearly that to-many relationships are *not* included in the possible kinds of properties:

> The property descriptions may represent attributes, to-one relationships, or expressions.